# How to predict using a multivariate regression function that is the sum of other regression functions

Tags: python, numpy, regression, statsmodels

I'm doing multivariate regression in python using the weighted least squares method.
I have a dataset that is 10x4, in other words, for each sample in the data, there are 4 features.

If my dataset is X, I can do the following to get the coefficients of the regression function:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.sandbox.regression.predstd import wls_prediction_std

mod_wls = sm.WLS(y, X)
res_wls = mod_wls.fit()
print res_wls.params
```

For my specific 10x4 dataset, this gives me the following output:

```
[ 0.06210193  5.24256099  0.15214974  0.12325115]
```

However, I've been told that I  need to build a regression function, `g(X)` by iterating over EACH `x[i]` in `X` and summing up the different regression functions.

I'm *guessing* (but would love to be corrected if I've understood this wrongly), I'm guessing that this means that `g(x) = g(x1) + g(x2) + g(x3) + ... + g(x10)`

So for eg. let's say the function for the first row of data gives the following coefficients:

```
[ 0.11  1.22  0.33  0.88]
```

and for the second row of data I get

```
[ 1.22  0.55  0.44  0.11]
```

So after two iterations, my `g(x)` should give the following coefficients:

```
[ 1.33  1.77  0.77  0.99]
```

Because for the first coefficient, 0.11 + 1.22 = 1.33, and so on. 
And so on until the tenth data sample.

Now my question is - how can regression functions be added in scikit-learn?

Iterating through each sample, grabbing the coefficients and adding them up individually - is that the only way to do this?

Let's say I've gotten the final coefficients, how can I now declare a regression model using these final coefficients so that I can pass data to it to predict values?

Comment: Are the `x[i]` single data points, i.e. there are 10 of them, or are there many `10x4` matrices. I do not understand why you would fit a model to each sample individually, it seems a lot more sensible to fit it to all your points together. Further, why are your params of size 3 instead of 4 (or 5 with intercept)?

Comment: X is one dataset which is one 10x4 matrix. There are ten rows, each row is x[i], and each row has 4 columns. So x[0] would be the first row and would return an array of four values. And x[0][1] would return the value in the first row and second column. Sorry I made a mistake with 3 params, I've edited the question, there should have been four. I'm fitting the model individually to each sample because I'm on step 2(a)(iii) of this algo: http://i.stack.imgur.com/d5C6P.png

Comment: If this is just a standard multiple regression, then you can just use `res_wls.predict(x)` to get your prediction. (In often used terminology multivariate regression has also several dependent, y variables.)

Comment: Thanks - but before that, is my summing up of the regression functions correct? And if so, then how can the functions be summed up in the first place? From what I understand, I can use predict on an existing regression model. But if I don't have a final regression function created by using **fit()**, and instead I've just taken the coefficients for the final function from the sum of all the coefficients of the previous regression functions, then how can I force the summed coefficients to be a new regression function on which I can then use **predict()**?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to just get the predictions back from the fitted equation developed by the weighted least squares equation.

In that case, g(X1,X2,X3,X4) = 0.06210193*X1 + 5.24256099*X2 + 0.15214974*X3 + 0.12325115*X4

Thus, for the first row in the dataset: [0.11  1.22  0.33  0.88]
g(0.11,1.22,0.33,0.88) = 0.06210193*0.11 + 5.24256099*1.22 + 0.15214974*0.33 + 0.12325115*0.88

or

g(0.11,1.22,0.33,0.88) = 6.561426046

If you'd like more information on multiple regression, you can find it here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-regression